# Как правильно преобразовать дату?

Tags: java, android

Есть данные в `String` `"2018-07-09T08:26:38.125+0000"`. Пытаюсь получить день месяц год час минута, написал метод:

```
public static String convertToDateAndTime(String dateTimeZone) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:S'Z'");
        Date newDate=formatter.parse(dateTimeZone);
        formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm");
        String date=formatter.format(newDate);
        return date;
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

> W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:
>   "2018-07-09T08:26:38.125+0000"

Answer (score 4):

Исправьте формат на: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Answer (score 3):

У вас неверный формат даты. Исходная строка у вас в формате ISO 8601, для которой правильный формат такой:

```
String ISO_8601_FORMAT_STRING="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
```

**Update:**

Z - Zulu time без кавычек

```
String ISO_8601_FORMAT_STRING="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
```

Comment: всеравно падает

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` - Z без кавычек

Comment: Да, все верно - Z без кавычек